# 2-particle hamiltonians numerical solution?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, many-body

Suppose I have a hamiltonian of the form 
$$H=\sum_{i,j}c_{ij}a^{\dagger}_ia_j+\sum_{i,j,k,l}v_{ijkl}a^{\dagger}_i a_j a^{\dagger}_k a_l$$
where $a^\dagger_i$ is the creation operator on site i. If $v_{ijkl}=0$ one can define the hamiltonian matrix; 
$$(H)_{n,n'}=<n'|H|n>$$
where |n> describes the wavefunction of the electron at the site n. From this one can calculate the eigenvalues of the hamiltonian by finding the eigenvalues of the hamiltonian matrix. If $v_{ijkl}\ne0$, the basis now is a direct product of the previous basis with itself (right?); $\{|n>\}\otimes\{|m>\}$. Then I can define the matrix $$(H)_{n,m,n',m'}=(<m'|\otimes<n'|)H(|n>\otimes|m>)$$For clarity, I can rewrite the hamiltonian as
$$H=H_1\otimes I+I\otimes H_1+\sum_{i,j,k,l}v_{ijkl}a^{\dagger}_ia_j \otimes a^{\dagger}_k a_l$$
and then calculate 
$$(H)_{n,m,n',m'}=\delta_{m,m'}(H)_{n,n'}+\delta_{n,n'}(H)_{m,m'}+v_{n',n,m',m}$$
One can write this as a matrix by inserting a step in say n and n'.For $n\in\{1,....N\}$ and $m\in\{1,....M\}$, I get an $NM\times NM$ matrix. $\textbf{Do the eigenvalues of this matrix give the full energy spectrum of the hamiltonian?}$
Is this analysis correct? I have not seen this anywhere in the bibliography I found. It seems resonable but when I try to find numerical results,if I start with a model that has band gap, and try this with $v_{ijkl}=0$, I get one big gapless band, which does not make sense.

Comment: You have to take into account that you have fermions!

Comment: That only constrains $v_{ijkl}$. I have not said much about that. Yes, I will indeed have to check that $v_{ikil}=0=v_{ijkj}$. Aslo, the hamiltonian must be hermitian; $v_{ijkl}=v^{*}_{jilk}$ and $c^{*}_{ji}=c_{ij}$. Thats not the point thought. It does not have to do with the highlighted question.

Comment: No, that is more than a constraint on $v$: It has the effect that the eigenvalues of $v$ (or whatever matrix) and the energy eigenvalues of the Hamiltonian are not the same - at least if you have fermions, which I tacitly assumed.  You might want to e.g. read up on the Jordan-Wigner transform.